# Laravel ORM select query function load() on null

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Here's my function to load submissions created by a user.

```
public function viewSubs()
{
    $user = User::find(Input::get('id'));
    $submissions  = Submission::find($user)->sortByDesc('created_at');

    $submissions->load('user')->load('votes')->load('suggestions.votes');

    return view('submissions.index' , compact('submissions'));
}
```

This returns with an error

> Call to a member function load() on null

when there are no records on the submission.

How to handle if there are no submission on the DB?

Comment: You need to circumvent the `null` case, you already got to this point, so I think a check for a `null` value is not that big of a challange for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if its `null` first using an if statement:

```
public function viewSubs()
{
    $user = User::find(Input::get('id'));

    if ($submissions  = Submission::find($user)->sortByDesc('created_at')) {
        $submissions->load('user')->load('votes')->load('suggestions.votes');
    }

    return view('submissions.index' , compact('submissions'));
}
```

Also, depending on your DB structure I'm pretty sure you can cut out a lot of the code by utilising your models' relationships by doing something like this:

```
$user = User::find(Input::get('id'))
    ->with(['submissions'  => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
    }, 'submissions.votes', 'submissions.suggestions.votes']);
```

Then pass the `$user` variable to the view, or:

```
$submissions = Submission::with('user', 'votes', 'suggestions.votes')
    ->where('user_id', Input::get('id'))
    ->sortByDesc('created_at')
    ->first();
```

Not entirely sure the code will work perfectly, but I'm sure you can tweak it. The point is your code can be a lot shorter and still/or more readable by using relationships you've already set up.